# I over-filled my Honda Rancher 400 AT 4X4 with oil and now it will not start

Tags: oil-change

I have an ATV 2006 HONDA RANCHER AT 400. I over-filled it with too much oil and now it will not start. Is this the cause of it not starting? I checked the spark plug and it’s good. I checked all fuses and they’re good.

Comment: Have you tried draining the oil down to the right level before trying to start the motor?

Comment: Does it turn over sufficiently fast?

Comment: outside the box question: added properly graded oil or something too thick?